# Sending mail using makeEWSRequestAsync() is failing to send body and attachment of email

Tags: office-js, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, outlook-web-addins

I have created an outlook addin to send emails with some attachments using 'makeEWSRequestAsync:CreateItem:SendAndSaveCopy' mechanism. Most of the times, this works as designed. It correctly sends out the email complete with the body and the attachments.

Unfortunately however, I found that my addin intermittently fails to send the body and attachments of the email. The email that my recipients receive has the headers but the email has no body and it has no attachment as well. This does not happen all the time, and not consistently.

I have checked the XML request and all looks good and properly formed with respect to schema. The characters have been escaped properly and resending the failing emails sometimes results to success.

My question then is, what can cause such a state where the EWS server receives the xml-request, server responds success but only sends the headers to the provided recipients. Is the email body malformed? Is the email size to big (16KB)? Or is this some setting with the Exchange server?

My Exchange server is 2016, and I don't know if this indeed is a server issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this document regarding [Createitem operation (email message)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/createitem-operation-email-message)

It contains sections for Success/Error responses for Createitem and how to interpret each element of the response. Hopefully this will help answer the reason why some of the EWS calls are failing intermittently.